# Min Date find from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query as per below:

```
SELECT
    IsTestBatch,
    BatchID,
    CampaignID,
    IF(ActualTriggerDateTime IS NOT NULL,
       MIN(ActualTriggerDateTime),
       MIN(TriggerDateTime)) AS NextQueuedOn
FROM
    campaignbatches
WHERE
    Status IN (2,3)
GROUP BY
    CampaignID
ORDER BY
    IF(ActualTriggerDateTime IS NOT NULL, ActualTriggerDateTime, TriggerDateTime) ASC
```

The `if` condition is not working properly, and the MIN date is not correct as I expect.

[image]

I expect the above record, but it returns the first record from the table for the previous image:

Comment: do you need just 1 row as a output ?

Comment: Please edit your question and instead show sample input along with the output you expect from the query.

Comment: Yes I need single row "GROUP BY CampaignID"

Answer (score 4):

Since the aggregation function `MIN()` ignore `NULL` values, you can try to select the minimum date from column **ActualTriggerDateTime**, and in the special case that all the values are NULL on this column, then select the minimum value from the column **TriggerDateTime**.

```
SELECT
    IsTestBatch,
    BatchID,
    CampaignID,
    IFNULL(MIN(ActualTriggerDateTime), MIN(TriggerDateTime)) AS NextQueuedOn
FROM
    campaignbatches
WHERE
    Status IN (2,3)
GROUP BY
    IsTestBatch, BatchID, CampaignID
ORDER BY
    NextQueuedOn ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

All the selection column will come to group by clause

```
SELECT IsTestBatch,BatchID,CampaignID,
 coalesce(MIN(ActualTriggerDateTime),MIN(TriggerDateTime)) AS NextQueuedOn 
 FROM campaignbatches
WHERE Status IN (2,3)
   and IsTestBatch=1 and BatchID=42 -- as you want single row
 GROUP BY IsTestBatch,BatchID,
   CampaignID 
ORDER BY NextQueuedOn ASC
```

Comment: Through error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
else MIN(TriggerDateTime) AS NextQueuedOn
FROM campaignbatches
WHERE Status' at line 3